# how to use a variable in the where clause to subset the dataframe in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I am new to pyspark. I was struggling with the following problem I am facing:

I have a dataframe named date_range:

```
date_range = spark.sql("SELECT sequence(date_add(current_date, -2), current_date(), interval 1 day) as date").withColumn("date", F.explode(F.col("date")))
display(date_range)
```

date
2021-11-13
2021-11-14
2021-11-15

I need to loop through each date in this df to subset another df named df_base like below:

```
for i in range(0, date_range.count()):
    d = date_range.collect()[i]
    df_temp = df_base.where("DPTR_DATE < 'd'")
    display(df_temp)
```

However, it returns the msg:
Query returned no results

df_base should look like something below: 
First   Last    DPTR_DATE
Daisy   Feng    2021-08-03
Daisy   Feng    2021-11-09
Daisy   Feng    2021-04-27
Daisy   Feng    2021-08-16

The code I used to generate df_base:\

```
data = [('Daisy', 'Feng', "2021-08-03"),
   ('Daisy', 'Feng', "2021-11-09"),
   ('Daisy', 'Feng', "2021-04-27"),
   ('Daisy', 'Feng', "2021-08-16")]
schema = StructType([
StructField('First', StringType()),
StructField('Last', StringType()),
StructField('DPTR_DATE', StringType())]
df_base = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=schema)
df_base = df_base.withColumn('DPTR_DATE', col('DPTR_DATE').cast(DateType()))
```

Since each date in DPTR_DATE is less than all three dates in df_range, I expect df_temp will be displayed three times, but it looks like nothing got returned.

Any help will he appreciated.
thanks,
Daisy

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code.

1. your sql query string inside `.where()` is not correct, as you are comparing DPTR_DATE  with string 'd' rather  than with date from date_range dataframe. You should change the query inside where to

   `"DPTR_DATE < '{}'".format(d)`
2. d inside loop needs to be changed as follows:

   `date_range.collect()[i][0]`

(or even better `date_range.select("date").collect()[i][0])`. Try to print the string query "DPTR_DATE < '{}'".format(d) to see why d needs to be modified like this and why the way you define will not work.

3. Also note that you are overwriting df_temp with each iteration of the loop, but you probably want to union the dataframes at each iteration.

Below is the modified version of the code based on these comments.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([], schema=df_base.schema)

for i in range(0, date_range.count()):
    d = date_range.collect()[i][0]
    df_temp = df_base.where("DPTR_DATE < '{}'".format(d))
    df = df.union(df_temp)
```

this will produce the following df

[image]

Comment: thanks for such a detailed reply. and thanks for pointing out the collect was not used appropriately. I was thinking date_range only has one column, so I might just need to refer to the row by [i].But seems like even the df has only one column, I still need to refer to the first column.